# Extending a block from another page

Tags: templating, matrix, block-types

My orignal website is a Onepager but I am creating a individual news page.

Is it possible to extend a block to another page taking over the content from that single? I have a block filled with a really big Matrix field which I cant have on my other page cause I only need a small amount of content from it. This content is placed inside a block so I need to extend just that block.

**What I need is to extend the {% block navigation %} and not the entire page**

See it as this:

```
{% block navigation %}
  {% for block in entry.blokken %}
    {% if block['opnemenInNavigatie'] is defined and block.opnemenInNavigatie %}
       <li>
        {% if block.navigatieNaam | slugify == 'news' %}
         <a href="/{{ block.navigatieNaam | slugify }}">          
          {{ block.navigatieNaam }} 
        </a>
       {% endif %}
      </li>
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

And also this:

```
{% block content %}
    {% for block in entry.blokken %}
        {% include 'blocks/' ~ block.type ~ '.html' %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: I'm not 100% following your question, but take a look at the Twig extend tag, I think that might be what you need http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/extends.html

Comment: Let me say it different because a posibillity might be setting a block in a variable that would do the deal too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd just put whatever you want to share into an include. Also you shouldn't need the `.html` either as craft should find the file

Comment: The solution was putting it all in a "set" variable and worked out fine now but it actually needs the `.html` because it is searching for just `.html` files in the blocks folder which is good because i have other types of files there some of them with the same name. Thanks for the answer though :D

Comment: Right on! Glad you were able to get it sorted out!